# Email verfication html and javascript

Tags: javascript, html, xhtml, email-validation

below is my code mainly for "Email Validation" but for some reason its not working properly i have no idea why , so do you mind taking a look please. thanks

I guess the main problem is with that line `document.getElementById("custEmail").onchange = chkEmail;` for some reason `chkEmail` is a problem...and also the search part `myEmail.value.search(+@[a-zA-Z_]+?.[a-zA-`

```
    <html  xmlns = "http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<title>Web Assignment 1 :Online shopping form</title>


<script type = "text/javascript">



      function chkEmail() {
        var myEmail = document.getElementById("custEmail");


        var pos = myEmail.value.search(+@[a-zA-Z_]+?.[a-zA-Z]{2,6});

        if (pos != 0) {
          alert("The email you entered (" + myEmail.value + 
                ") is not in the correct form. \n" +
                "The correct form is: " +
                "whatever@whatever.xxx\n" +
"Please fix it");
          myEmail.focus();
          myEmail.select();
          return false;
        } else
          return true;
      }


    </script>
</head>
<body>
<h1> Please fill in the information below </h1>

<form action="" 
>
<p>
<h2> Contact Info...</h2>
<pre>
     Last  Name     :  <input type="text" name="name2" size="20">
     Email          :  <input type="email" id = "custEmail" onchange ="chkEmail();" size="30">
     Mobile number  :  <input type="text" name="mob" size="15">
    </pre>
 <input type = "reset"  id = "reset" />
<input type = "submit"  id = "submit" />
  </p>

 </form>
 <script type = "text/javascript">
      <!--
// Set form element object properties to their 
// corresponding event handler functions

        document.getElementById("custEmail").onchange = chkEmail;
      // -->
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: where did you take that `.search(+@[a-zA-Z_]+?.[a-zA-Z]{2,6})` ? Have a look at https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions

Comment: Also, please explain "no working properly" and make a jsFiddle out of this so that we can see it in action. Oh and keep in mind that the ONLY real validation occurs on SERVER-SIDE. Client-side validation is for user-friendlyness only.

Comment: To validate a email I would send a request to my server with the email, do [Punycode](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Punycode) encode,  check if the domain exists using a dns request, and do an initial smtp handshake to see if the smtp server for the domain would accept the email. Most of the RegExp for emails out there are wrong or incomplete.

Comment: yes i only want client side verification.

Comment: when i run it and enter an invalid email nothing happens it accepts it no alert is shown(ps. Im using Safari)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you just want a client side validation, why don't you just simply validate using HTML regular expression as follows:
If you just want a client side validation, why don't you just simply validate using HTML regular expression as follows:

```
<form action="">
<p>
<h2> Contact Info...</h2>
<pre>
    Last  Name     :  <input type="text" name="name2" size="20">
    Email          :  <input type="email" id = "custEmail" size="30" pattern="[^@]+@[^@]+\.[a-zA-Z]{2,6}">
    Mobile number  :  <input type="text" name="mob" size="15">
</pre>
<input type = "reset"  id = "reset" />
<input type = "submit"  id = "submit" />
</form>
```

See fiddle here:
http://jsfiddle.net/9gthN/